# About C: pointer and Two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here is the question:
What is the output of the program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int  A[2][10]={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}   };
int (*v)[10]=A;

printf("**v=%d\n",**v);
printf("**(v+1)=%d\n",**(v+1));
printf("*(*v+1)=%d\n",*(*v+1));
printf("*(v[0]+1)=%d\n",*(v[0]+1));
printf("*(v[1])=%d\n",*(v[1]));
}
```

Outputs:

```
**v=1
**(v+1)=11
*(*v+1)=2
*(v[0]+1)=2
*(v[1])=11
```

Especially, I'm not very clear about how did *v divide array A into 10 parts, and please tell me the reasons about each output.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There's a concept called [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) at work. Also, pass each definition through [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/).

The second line is

> declare v as pointer to array 10 of int

Thus it is a pointer to an array of 10 elements. This pointer is initialized with `A` -- the array it points to is the first row of `A`.

Then, `v+1` is another pointer to an array of 10 elements, following the first one. Thus, it is the second row of `A`.

Comment: +1 For the cdecl link! Exceptional :-) :-) (and highly ironic I would say)

Answer (score 3):

1. In the `**v`, `*v` will be replaced by value of `v[0]`, which is an address, say `X`, therefore the outer `*` will be used to indicate the value of address `X`, which is `1`.
2. In the `**(v+1)`, `*(v+1)` will become `v[1]`, which is again an address, say `Y`, and the outer asterisk will give the value at address `Y`, which is `11`.
3. `*(*v+1)=2` => `*(v[0] + 1)` => here pointer shifts to the next location, and this location is `v[0][1]`, which is similar to `*(*(v+0)+1)`. Value at `v[0][1]` is `2`.
4. `*(v[0]+1)=2`, same reason.
5. `*(v[1])=11`, `v[1]` holds the base address of the second row, which is the starting address of second row's `0`th column, and the value at that location is `11`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's review first, how arrays decay and second, how declarations work.

`A` is declared as a 2D array. When `A` is used in any expression, it will "decay" to a pointer to its first element. In C, a 2D array is made up of two 1D arrays. So an element of a 2D array is a 1D array. So when `A` is used in any expression, it will decay to a pointer to the first row of `A`, which is an array of 10 ints.

`int (*v) [10]` means that `v` is a pointer to an array of 10 ints. The assignment

```
int (*v)[10] = A;
```

is an expression, so `A` there has decayed to a pointer to 10 ints as well, so the assignment is valid.

So now when you look at `**v`, you are dereferencing first, `v`, which means you are getting what `v` points at, which is the first row of your 2D array. Then you are dereferencing `*v`, which means you are getting the first element of that first row. That is 1, so your output is 1.

When you look at `**(v + 1)`, you are first adding 1 to the pointer `v`. Since `v` points to a row, adding 1 gets you a pointer to the next row. Then you do the double dereferencing as above and you get the first element of the next row, which is 11.

When you look at `*(*v + 1)`, you are first dereferencing `v`, which means you get the first row. Then you add 1 to that,  which gets you a pointer to the next element of the row. Then you dereference that, which gets you the 2, the second element.

To summarize: `v` points to the whole first row. `*v` points to the first element of the first row. `(v + 1)` points to the whole second row. `(*v + 1)` points to the second element of the first row.

After this, figuring out the rest is probably quite easy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think here assigning 10 elements to v makes me confused. In fact,     int (*v)[2] is enough.

Comment: No, it won't be enough. `(*v)[2]` would be a pointer to an array of 2 ints. Each row in `A` is an array of 10 ints. You really need `(*v)[10]`.